# JPQL LIKE syntax with Strings

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa, jpql

EDIT:

I changed the hard coded query to be:

```
 query.setParameter("desc", "%unplug //your// server... enjoy the freedom%" ESCAPE '//')
```

and now I am getting an `com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.`

There's no stacktrace produced either.

I have a description column in my PostgreSQL database and I am trying to query it with a 'LIKE' clause, however I am unable to get any results.  Here's an example:

```
    Query query = em.createQuery("from MyClass c WHERE c.description LIKE :desc");
    query.setParameter("desc", "%unplug /your/ server... enjoy the freedom%");
```

In the database I have many descriptions containing a substring of the above text.  I've done a lot of research and looked into escaping special chars etc, but nothing has worked.

I am missing something, I just cannot figure out what that is.

Comment: Does your description really contain "/your/"? What happend when you use `%e%` instead?

Comment: Yes, it does.  It's scraped text with some unusual markup.  When you ask if I've tried %e%, do you mean literally "%e%" or the escape sequence `%E` ?

Comment: No, I mean literally `%e%`. I'm sure you have a description mathing %e%. I'm not so sure you have one matching your long parameter. If the query works with `%e%`, then it means your parameter is wrong. If it doesn't work with `%e%`, then you'll have to look elsewhere for the reason.

Comment: Will play with it when I get back into work.  Thanks for the advice

Comment: What exception are you getting it seems **select c from MyClass c** is the correct start of the query

Comment: No exception, just an empty list

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the slash / is messing up the parsing in PG. Turn the parameter into a quoted literal. Unless you are certain that no special characters go into string arguments (i.e. you control the strings), this is **always** a good idea to avoid SQL injection.

```
query.setParameter("desc", "quote_literal('%unplug /your/ server... enjoy the freedom%')");
```

Comment: Thanks @Patrick; I'll try that tomorrow.  I wish JPA had something like that so we didn't have to get into DB specific functionality to make it work.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Have you tried JB Nizet's approach of working with an uncomplicated string to match?

Comment: Patrick, I have tried his approach and it works.  It seems to be the special chars that are throwing everything off

Comment: Tren try in parts. Try things like "server...", "/your/", etc. The first should work, the second I am not so sure. Also look in the postgresql logs if you can find any error entries there. A radically different solution is to go with the text search extension: look up section 9.13 of the documentation.

Comment: Turns out it was my toString() method causing a circular dependency.  I fixed the method and added em.delete(); em.flush() in my DAO and all works as expected.  Thanks for everyone's input